# .net c++/CLI combobox valueMember nullReferenceException

Tags: .net, combobox, c++-cli, nullreferenceexception

I have an Experiment class. I created some instances of this class and populate combobox with these objects. I used DisplayMember and ValueMember properties. The population is OK, but when I read the selectedValue from the combobox, it gives me NullReferenceException.

Here is my code:

```
public ref class ABC
{
    ABC( Experiment^ exp )
    {
        this->exp = exp;
        this->name = this->exp->getName();
    }
    property Experiment^ Exp
    {
        Experiment^ get()
        {
            return this->exp;
        }
    }
    property String^ Name
    {
        String^ get()
        {
            return this->name;
        }
    }

    Experiment^ exp;
    String^ name;
}
```

```
Experiment^  e1;
this->combobox->Items(gcnew ABC(e1));
this->combobox->DisplayMember = "Name";
this->combobox->ValueMember = "Exp";

this->combobox->SelectedIndex = 0;

Experiment^  e2 = (Experiment^)(this->combobox->SelectedValue); // nullReferenceException
```

Comment: Post code that can actually be compiled.  Passing an uninitialized Experiment object to the ABC constructor is unwise.  There is otherwise no obvious way I see to repro the exception.

Comment: `ComboBox::Items` is a property, not a method; I agree with Hans, the code is bogus.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why but when I exchange the following line

```
Experiment^  e2 = (Experiment^)(this->combobox->SelectedValue);
```

with this line

```
Experiment^  e2 = ((ABC^)(this->combobox->SelectedItem))->Exp;
```

it is Ok, this fixed the problem.